# How to add color to text in my div with code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

Hi I have my divs with code and I want to add style css for coloring my code inside my div

how to coloring this code in c#

```
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
    private void BindDummyRow()
    {
    DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
    dummy.Columns.Add("");
    dummy.Rows.Add();
    gv.DataSource = dummy;
    gv.DataBind();
    }
    </div>
```

how to coloring this code in css

```
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
    <style>
    .panel {
    border: 3px solid #3B98EE;
    }
    </style>
    </div>
```

how to coloring this code in sql

```
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
    Select * from table
    </div>
```

how to coloring this code in javascript

```
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
    $(function () {
    code();
    });
    </div>
```

how to coloring this code in html

```
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    </div>
```

Etc.
Thanks!

Comment: You want to add a class or id onto the div you want to style, then refer to it by that class or id in the style.css

Comment: I hope you don't mean to highlight the syntax of each language. But only to change background, @ajmajmajma give you the tip.

Comment: Have a look at [Google code prettifier](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) There is a demo [here](https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/examples/quine.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to try accomplishing this through styles alone. What you want is a script to help you with syntax highlighting, such as highlight.js, perhaps (https://highlightjs.org/)

From the usage site, you can do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css">
<script src="/path/to/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

<pre><code class="html">
<a href="#">This is an example</a>
</code></pre>
```

If you'd like to highlight static content rather than anything dynamically, there are tools online to help you with that, such as http://tohtml.com/

Comment: Just want to note that OP will need to use PRE or CODE tags as shown by Rein. A DIV tag would not display the content correctly.